# Oracle 6.5: MySQL Daemon failed to start

Tags: mysql, installation, oracle, daemon, daemontools

I installed MySQL by following [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/linux-installation-native.html) on my Oracle Linux Server release 6.5, specifically using the yum package installer command,

```
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-libs mysql-server
```

However I repeatedly keep getting the following error:

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld: [FAILED]
```

I tried to resolve the issue by following all suggestions provided by [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mysql-daemon-failed-to-start-845353/)  because my `mysql.dock` file did not exist after repeatedly trying to find it's path with the `locate`, `whereis`, and `find` commands.

After this didn't work, I killed all sql processes and I uninstalled the software by using the following command

```
killall mysqld
killall mysqld_safe
yum remove mysql-server
```

I then tried installing the MySQL with rpm files with no luck and the same error. I also tried to do an upgrade with no luck.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue? I am extremely new to oracle servers/linux, so I apologize for the simplicity of this question. Please let me know what additional information I need to provide if any.

Comment: Watch the `mysql` and system logs for errors that explain why MySQL won't start.